# error when using tkinter + sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to use sqlite3 in a gui (Tkinter) here, and when I try to compile the code using geany,  its return this error

```
File "/home/armando/Documents/curso/python_projects/sqlite3.py", line 3
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file /home/armando/Documents/curso/python_projects/sqlite3.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

How I can solve this?

Thanks

Light and peace!

Comment: It will be better if you add your code's problematic part by editing your question.

Answer (score 1):

See pep 263 - http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

You have to declare your encoding at the top of your source module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Replace utf-8 with whatever encoding you've saved the file with.

Comment: hi @jaime, I solved this problem
I simple change the order of my import evocation
before was 
"from Tkinter import *
 import sqlite3"

then I put the "import sqlite3" in the first line and its compile properlly

thank you!

Comment: Glad you worked that out!  It's strange that reordering the imports fixed it.  Take care!

Comment: why? what can happen?

Comment: It means that one module is affecting the other.  If that particular module ever changes in such a way that it no longer `fixes` your problem, then you don't know why / what happened.

Comment: I have reinstaled the sqlite and sqlite-devel before, but when I change the import order the problem desapear and before this, it dont occur more, so I dont know how the problem get right, so if this occur, how I can solve this?
thank you!